# Sort Google Forms responses on Submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-forms

I have three columns in my Sheet where Google Forms store response data: Gender, Name and Email.
If user sends form with Gender-field value equals "Male" I want to store this response to existing sheet named "Males".
Here is my solution(I've already added special trigger for it and here is event hendler implimentation), but it doesn't work:

```
function onItemAdd(e) {
  var formData = e.values;
  if (formData[0] == "Male") {
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Males").getDataRange().getValues()[0];
    var formRow = e.range;
    var filteredCell = formRow.getCell(1, formRow.getLastColumn()).offset(0, 1).setValue(formData);
  }
}
```

Comment: another approach might be to filter out the data from the sheet using formulas.  You can use the ez query sheet add-on to easily create an live sheet with just the males.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `values` property for the On Form Submit event object.  There are only 3 properties of the On Form Submit event object.

- authMode
- response
- source

`source` gets the form.  `response` gets the form response.

```
var thisResponse = e.response.getItemResponses();
var gender = thisResponse[0].getResponse();

Logger.log('gender: ' + gender);
```